# How do I use an external speaker and mic?

Tags: macbook-pro, speakers, microphone

I need to attach a mic and a speaker to my Macbook for a conference at work so that multiple listeners can hear, this rules out a headset. Can I attach both through one jack?

Comment: I've removed the shopping recommendation portion of your question. Do take a moment to review the site's help pages about allowed topics.

Comment: If you don't have separate sockets (this varies by model) then you can buy a "splitter" cable that splits out mike and headphone as two separate sockets.  Apple doesn't sell these cables (to my knowledge), and the droids at Best Buy et al will just give you a dumb look if you ask for one, but you can find them on the internet. (You do, of course, need a powered speaker to amplify the headphone signal.)

Comment: (Hint: It's the same splitter cable you'd use on an iPhone to split headphone and mike.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, MacBooks have a desperate mic and speaker socket on the side. If this is not the case, then which model do you have?

Comment: Macbook pro it has only one jack at the side. I do have a speaker but when I plug this in it takes away from the Mic sound. I heard about a USB mic do you think this could be a sloution?

Comment: Oh right, I see now, the newer ones only have a headphone socket. Yes, a USB mic would work.